# PRESTASHOP 1.7.6: Display the unit price on all pages of the website, not just on the product page

Tags: templates, hook, prestashop-1.7, price

I am looking for a module or other that would allow me to display the unit price of a product on all the pages of my website. For example I have my homepage with my new products, and I would like the unit price to be displayed between the price of my product and the add to cart button.
So I already have the unit price displayed in the product page, prestashop does it natively by checking an option but it doesn't do it for the rest of the website.
I've already tried to put this code in my tpl files but without any success...

```
{block name='product_unit_price'}
   {if $displayUnitPrice}
      <p class="product-unit-price sub">{l s='(%unit_price%)' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%unit_price%' => $product.unit_price_full]}</p>
   {/if}
{/block}
```

I'm not an expert in prestashop tpl files and hooks, I must be doing it wrong.
I need help please, anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a Prestashop module connected to the `displayProductPriceBlock` hook.

I think this could help you, this hook is used on the following templates:

```
/themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl
/themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/product-prices.tpl
/themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-summary-product-line.tpl
/themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/order-confirmation-table.tpl
```

Don't hesitate if I can help!

Comment: Is it possible to display the unit price only for a selection of products? For example, if one of my items has the unit price entered in the back office of presta, can I retrieve this variable and display only the prices when the variable is present?

Comment: Hi, Yes it's possible :)
You can add a if statement to check if unit price is filled before show the unit price